# CSS Display: Flex on Desktop and Mobile

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm newer to using FLEXBOX and have a question on a layout using Desktop and Mobile.

I'm displaying info using a label and data (not on a form).

On the desktop, I'd like it to display like this:

label-------label-------label------label

Data--------Data--------Data-------Data

On a desktop, label and data will be a % based on number of elements.

But, on a mobile, I'd like it to display like this:

label------
Data-------

Label------
Data-------

label------
data-------

Label------
Data-------

label------
data-------

On mobile, I'd like label and data to be 25% & 75% wide.

Not sure on the HTML if it should be laid out like this

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="label">Label</div>
   <div class="data">Data</a>
   <div class="label">Label</div>
   <div class="data">Data</a>
   <div class="label">Label</div>
   <div class="data">Data</a>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="label">label</div>
   <div class="label">label</div>
   <div class="label">label</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="data">data</div>
   <div class="data">data</div>
   <div class="data">data</div>
</div>
```

Any guidance would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: it's indeed the place to ask questions but not to ask *I don't know how to do, do it for me* ... You are simply listing your requirements add waiting for us to do it for you, so this is not a programming question. SO isn't a helpdesk or a forum (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Fair enough.  I did try and fail on my attempts, so thought SO was a good place to contact other programmers for help.

Comment: `I did try and fail on my attempts` --> simply share your attempts (or at least one) and it will be a valid question ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're flexible on the HTML structure.
I recommend grouping data pairs with parent elements, making columns and rows.
With two nested flexboxes, you can change `flex-direction` as desired.

```js
/* FOR DEMO PURPOSES */
var $body = $('body');
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $body.toggleClass('small');
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  padding: .25em .5em;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .container {
    background-color: lightblue;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .group {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}




/* FOR DEMO PURPOSES */

.small .container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.small .group {
  flex-direction: row;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="item label">Label 1</div>
    <div class="item data">Data 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="item label">Label 2</div>
    <div class="item data">Data 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="item label">Label 3</div>
    <div class="item data">Data 3</div>
  </div>
</div>


<button>Simulate Size Change</button>
```

Here's a demo with more than one row of data:

```js
/* FOR DEMO PURPOSES */
var $body = $('body');
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $body.toggleClass('small');
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item {
  padding: .25em .5em;
}
.label {
  font-weight:bold;
}
.flag {
  color:red;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .container {
    background-color: lightblue;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .group {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}


/* FOR DEMO PURPOSES */

.small .container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.small .group {
  flex-direction: row;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="item label">Label 1</div>
    <div class="item data">Data 1a</div>
    <div class="item data flag">Data 1b</div>
    <div class="item data">Data 1c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="item label">Label 2</div>
    <div class="item data">Data 2a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="item label">Label 3</div>
    <div class="item data">Data 3a</div>
    <div class="item data">Data 3b</div>
  </div>
</div>


<button>Simulate Size Change</button>
```

---

For more ideas, I highly recommend reading [Accessible, Simple, Responsive Tables @ CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/) and checking out the [other resources](https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/#other-responsive-tables-resources) listed there.

Answer (score 0):

I would order them like the first option. Then, at desktop view I'd make a `flex flow` of `column wrap`, set a height for the container and set each `flex-item` to be 50% height.

On mobile, id switch to `flex-flow: row wrap`, and define the container's width, then each child at 25%/75% depends on which child.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="label">Label</div>
   <div class="data">Data</a>
   <div class="label">Label</div>
   <div class="data">Data</a>
   <div class="label">Label</div>
   <div class="data">Data</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  height: 500px; // what ever you want here
}

.label, .data {
  height: 45% // Less than 50% for margins, etc.
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) { //Set desired width to call 'mobile'
  .container {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: unset;
    height: 500px; //Whatever you want again
  }

  .data {
    width: 70%;
  }

  .label {
    width: 22%;
  }
}
```